# Phalcon Installation on Ubuntu 13.10, PHP 5.5 - invalid opcode

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, phalcon

I have installed Phalcon using the instructions in the download page on a brand new server with Ubuntu 13.10, Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5

When I try to run the test/default application I am seeing this in the Apache logs:

```
[Wed Apr 02 18:46:14.381872 2014] [core:notice] [pid 7634] AH00052: child pid 7639 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)
```

Additional hunting and tracking I ran across this in dmesg

```
[1156560.603934] traps: php[5067] trap invalid opcode ip:7fa191d7ddc8 sp:7fffa291e4c0 error:0 in phalcon.so[7fa191c18000+28d000] [1157014.697160] traps: php[6185] trap invalid opcode ip:7ff2b48f5dc8 sp:7fff678e6f00 error:0 in phalcon.so[7ff2b4790000+28d000]
[1157054.064211] traps: php[6205] trap invalid opcode ip:7ff3f4deddc8 sp:7fff6d8f26c0 error:0 in phalcon.so[7ff3f4c88000+28d000] [1157071.808218] traps: php[6256] trap invalid opcode ip:7faee68eddc8 sp:7fffa58c37b0 error:0 in phalcon.so[7faee6788000+28d000]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling Phalcon this way:

```
cd cphalcon/build/safe
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fvisibility=hidden"
phpize 
./configure --enable-phalcon
make
sudo make install
```